# ng-grid column resize on IE behaves strangely when the column resize is ended outside window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

This issue can be very easily seen on IE with ng-grid (it is fine on Chrome and Firefox) -

http://plnkr.co/edit/CrQzzWQZzs3hZP7BJCFc?p=preview

In the above plunkr, there is a reference to

```
enableColumnResize: true
```

If you resize the column by dragging (on IE) and if you end the drag outside the window (releasing the mouse outside the window), then it thinks "resize" is still happening. Thereafter a simple mouse movement will cause the column to resize (mouse down is not required) like madness.

If anyone is aware of this issue (like a bug report or something), please let me know.

Comment: Which IE? Some versions of IE have wierd box-models that don't behave normally.

Comment: Definitely seen on IE10 and IE11. I do not have immediate access to earlier versions.

Comment: Any resolution...we just encountered the same issue  :(